# Installing RTL8811CU WiFi drivers without internet

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have a desktop with Ubuntu. I have purchased a wifi adaptor which came with its drivers. Could you please help me install the drivers? I can see there is a shell script that I don't know how to run them.
Please note that I don't have an internet connection to this device. It would have been much easier if I did.
I have attached herewith the files that I have in the driver folder.
Please let me know if you require anything further details.
Your help will be really appreciated.

Thanks[image: Files that I have in the driver folder]

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Drivers are actually kernel modules, thus your kernel stack matters & as we don't know your Ubuntu product/release, we can't know which kernel stack you're using or what options you have available.  Is what has been provided compatible with your *unstated* Ubuntu product & kernel stack choice?  Knowing what you're running is first required detail (*particularly the release or version detail*)   You can download required files on another device, write to thumb-drive and install using that media if necessary too.